# Invalid Argument from sendto() Socket Program in C

Tags: c, sockets, client-server, unix-socket

I'm trying to make a simple client-server API to be used for two of my machines. I made this simple program that uses the functions I made to test it. For some reason my client sends a message just fine, but my server can't (however, it receives the message from the client).

Server side output:

```
 host name: my_host
 Our port number is: 34440
 Client msg: Client msg
 Send failed: Invalid argument
 Message from Server sent to Client
```

Client side output:

```
 Connection established with server...
 Message from Client sent to Server
```

Server side:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "my_socket.h"

int main() {

    server_init();
    char *msg = "Server msg";
    char buffer[100];

    int n = read_from_client((char *)buffer);
    buffer[n] = '\0';
    printf("Client msg: %s\n", buffer);
    write_to_client((char *)msg);
    printf("Message from Server sent to Client \n");   
    return 0;
}
```

Client Side:

```
   #include <sys/socket.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <fcntl.h>
   #include <pthread.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include "my_socket.h"

   int main() {

   client_init();
   char *msg = "Client msg";
   char buffer[100];

   write_to_server((char*)msg);
   printf("Message from Client sent to Server \n");
   int n = read_from_server((char *)buffer);
   buffer[n] = '\0';
   printf("Server msg: %s\n", buffer);

   close_socket();  
   return 0;
 }
```

my_socket.c:

```
#include "my_socket.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>

   int sockfd1;
   int sockfd2;
   int MAX_BUFF = 1024;
   struct sockaddr_in server;
   struct sockaddr_in client;
   struct hostent *host;

   ssize_t write_to_server(const void *buffer){
      int bytes_sent, server_size = sizeof(server), buf_len = strlen(buffer);
      if ((bytes_sent = sendto(sockfd2, buffer, buf_len, 0, 
            (const struct sockaddr *)&server, server_size)) < 0){
     perror("Send failed");
      }
      return bytes_sent;
   }

   ssize_t write_to_client(const void *buffer){
      int bytes_sent, client_size = sizeof(client), buf_len = strlen(buffer);
      if ((bytes_sent = sendto(sockfd1, buffer, buf_len, 0, 
            (const struct sockaddr *)&client, client_size)) < 0){
     perror("Send failed");
      }
      return bytes_sent;
   }

   int read_from_server(void *buffer){
      int bytes_rcv, len;
      if ((bytes_rcv = recvfrom(sockfd2, buffer, MAX_BUFF, MSG_WAITALL, 
                   (struct sockaddr *)&server, &len)) < 0){
     perror("Read failed");
      }
      return bytes_rcv;
   }

   int read_from_client(void *buffer){
      int bytes_rcv, len;
      if ((bytes_rcv = recvfrom(sockfd1, buffer, MAX_BUFF, MSG_WAITALL, 
                   (struct sockaddr *)&client, &len)) < 0){
     perror("Read failed");
      }
      return bytes_rcv;
   }


   void close_socket() {
      close(sockfd1);
      close(sockfd2);
   }

   void server_init(){
      if ( (sockfd1 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) {
     perror("socket creation failed");
      }
      char name[1024];
      name[1023] = '\0';
      gethostname(name, 1023);
      printf("host name: %s \n", name);

      host = gethostbyname("my_host");
      if(host == NULL){
     perror("Host is null");
     exit(0);
      }

      bzero((char *)&server, sizeof(server));
      bzero((char *)&client, sizeof(client));

      server.sin_family          = AF_INET;
      bcopy((char *)host->h_addr, 
        (char *)&server.sin_addr.s_addr, host->h_length);
      //server.sin_port            = 0; 
      server.sin_port            = htons(34440);

      if ( (bind(sockfd1, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server) ) ) < 0 ){
     perror("bind failed");
      } 
      socklen_t len = sizeof(server);
      if (getsockname(sockfd1, (struct sockaddr *)&server, &len) == -1){
     perror("getsockname");
      }else{
     printf("Our port number is: %d\n", ntohs(server.sin_port));
      }
   }

   void client_init(){

      if ( (sockfd2 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) {
     perror("socket creation failed");
      }

      host = gethostbyname("my_host");
      if(host == NULL){
     perror("Host is null");
     exit(0);
      }

      bzero((char *)&server, sizeof(server));

      server.sin_family       = AF_INET;
      bcopy((char *)host->h_addr, 
        (char *)&server.sin_addr.s_addr, host->h_length);
      //server.sin_port = 0; 
      server.sin_port = htons(34440);

      if(connect(sockfd2, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) == 0){
     printf("Connection established with server...\n");
      }

   }
```

my_socket.h:

```
#ifndef MY_SOCKET
#define MY_SOCKET
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>


extern int sockfd1;
extern int sockfd2;
extern int MAX_BUFF;
extern struct sockaddr_in server;
extern struct sockaddr_in client;
extern struct hostent *host;


// Send a message over the socket  
ssize_t write_to_server(const void *buffer);
ssize_t write_to_client(const void *buffer);

// Blocks until told it's ready; receives bytes from socket 
int read_from_server(void *buffer);
int read_from_client(void *buffer);   

// Close the socket
void close_socket();

void server_init();

void client_init();      


#endif
```

Any advice or criticism is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Along with the answers below, don't make it a habit of ignoring the type aliases provided by the networking libraries, and specified in the API documentation for each API call. They're important. There are multitude of places where `socklen_t`, `ssize_t`, and `size_t` should be used, where you're just stuffing everything in `int` variables instead. Trust me; that can bite you in the most subtle and hard-to-debug ways. Follow the rules.

Comment: The changes have been made. Thanks for the warning!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least one issue is that you are not initializing the `len` variable in `read_from_client`. The manual page for `recvfrom` says, in part (emphasis added):

> ... `addrlen` is a value-result  argument. **Before the call, it should be initialized to the size of the buffer associated with `src_addr`.**  Upon return, `addrlen` is updated to contain the actual size of the source address.  The returned address is truncated if the buffer provided is too small; in this case, `addrlen` will return a value greater than was supplied to the call.

That means that, as an uninitialized stack variable, `len` has an indeterminate value. Probably zero, but at least something smaller than `sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)`. As a result, `client` is not getting filled in correctly by the `recvfrom`.

Just before the `recvfrom`, you should initialize it with:

```
len = sizeof(client);
```

On the client side, `write_to_server` and `read_from_server` need not use `recvfrom` and `sendto` as you have already done a `connect` on the socket. They can simply use `recv` and `send` since the remote socket endpoint is already established by the `connect`. I believe the address is simply ignored for a connected socket, but I cannot find where that is documented right now.

(In any case, if you *do* continue to use `recvfrom` on the client side, you should make the same `len` initialization there.)